# I guarantee you everyone's had one at least once... (Well, maybe not *some* people)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's an easy one, since the 50th puzzle is still being solved.

> I'm as tall as the largest mountain, but can fit in your hand.
> I can be spread out like a fountain, slip through fingers like sand.
>
> I can plague you for days, like an itch on the back of your neck.
> Or I can astound and amaze, and give you one large paycheck.

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm not physical.

Comment: You created your $50$th puzzle? Congratulations! :)

Comment: Would the correct answer work any better when spoken than when written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> an Idea

I'm as tall as the largest mountain, but can fit in your hand.

> some big ideas can be written in a piece of paper

I can be spread out like a fountain, slip through fingers like sand.

> Some people spread their ideas by speech or writing
>  and, If you didn't pay attention to your idea, your idea might be forgotten (or stolen)

I can plague you for days, like an itch on the back of your neck.

> "An idea is like a virus, resilient, highly contagious", Cobb (Inception, 2010)

Or I can astound and amaze, and give you one large paycheck.

> Good and implemented idea will give you some rewards even money

Comment: Sorry, this is my first chance to see this answer. This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm as tall as the largest mountain, but can fit in your hand.

> A tall tale can fit in a small book.

I can be spread out like a fountain, slip through fingers like sand.

> Can spread wildly or easily lost.

I can plague you for days, like an itch on the back of your neck.

> Cliff-hangers... I want to know how it ends.

Or I can astound and amaze, and give you one large paycheck.

> People sell stories, some with shock and awe.

Comment: This is great, but not quite what I had in mind. It certainly fits, though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Computer?

I'm as tall as the largest mountain, but can fit in your hand.

> Computers can have cloud backup and you can hold a laptop with one hand.

I can be spread out like a fountain, slip through fingers like sand.

> Maybe the wifi network?

I can plague you for days, like an itch on the back of your neck.

> I may spend to much time on my computer, lurking on puzzling.

Or I can astound and amaze, and give you one large paycheck.

> You can be a programmer, or access your bank on the computer.

The title

> Some people here use the computer while others use mobile.

And,

> El-Guest said the first letters, IIIO, stand for "Intel Inside, Idiot Outside"

**NEW ANSWER**

Are you a

> An solved riddle?

I'm as tall as the largest mountain, but can fit in your hand.

> There are some big questions.

I can be spread out like a fountain, slip through fingers like sand.

> You may have an answer for some puzzles but other answers may slip you mind.

I can plague you for days, like an itch on the back of your neck.

> Myabe the question has a bounty on it and you still cannot answer it.

Or I can astound and amaze, and give you one large paycheck.

> You may find the answer to an awesome puzzle and maybe receive up votes and a bounty.

And,

> Questions and answers are not physical. and some people on this site have not answered questions.

Comment: And, my favourite part, rot13(Gur svefg yrggref, VVVB, fgnaq sbe "Vagry Vafvqr, Vqvbg Bhgfvqr"!)

Comment: My pleasure! Great answer though, you were super quick today!! :)

Comment: It's not this, though this is great. :D

Comment: It's not this either, though this is WAY closer to the actual answer.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I would answer with this ro13(Pbhyq vg or na nafjre?), but I just want to check first.

Comment: No, you could say both rot13(Dhrfgvbaf naq Nafjref ner n cneg bs jung gur nafjre vf)

Comment: It sounds like it could be a rot13(Chmmyr ba FR)? But I'd be pretty much copying QuantumTwinkie's answer, apart from the last line which could be the rot13(cnlbss bs svanyyl fbyivat n qvssvphyg chmmyr). Probably fairer to give them a chance to change it

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I made a change to my answer.